# Grid with a missing pass

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

In the diagram, note that the grid path from F to G is missing, so paths from D to E cannot pass between F and G. How many paths are there from D to E? (Assume we can only move up or right.)

[image]

I ended up getting$$\binom{8}{5} - \binom{4}{2}\binom{3}{2} = 38$$Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @MikeEarnest as we know this types of questions can be solved by Pascals triangle method . However , when i apply it , i encountered a problem in point $G$. I  found that point $G$ must be $10+4=14$ . However , it is equal to $10-4=6$ to satify the answer. Do you know any explanation for it ?

Comment: @Bulbasaur $G$ must be the sum of the labels of the points which are adjacent to it and earlier in the path. $G$ is only adjacent to the point below it, so $G$ should be labeled with $4$. You do not add in the $10$, since the $10$ paths leading to $F$ do not contribute to the paths leading to $G$, as there is no $F-G$ connection. (Also, the $F$ label is supposed to be $6$, not $10$.)

Comment: @MikeEarnest oh , i forgot that only move right and top . Thanks for answering !

Answer (score 2):

A cross-check by counting the lattice paths from $D$ to $E$ using $(1,0)$-steps and $(0,1)$-steps shows the calculation is correct.

[image]